# How to add custom ini_set in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I want to export data from a view into `CSV` file at live server but whenever I run it I get this error:

**Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

And here is the Export Class:

```
class StudentExportView implements FromView {
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function view(): View {
        $student = new Student();
        $students = $student->searchStudents()->paginate(10);
        $custom = new Student();
        $customs = $custom->all();
        return view('admin.students.custom', compact('students','customs'));
    }
}
```

And at the **Controller**:

```
public function export_view() {
    return Excel::download(new StudentExportView, 'studentlist.csv');
}
```

Actually, there is a large amount of data, that's why this error occurred. But they say if I add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` I can get rid of this error.

So the question is where to add this custom `ini_set`? I mean at the Controller or Export Class?

Is there any solution to run this code on a live server?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write at the beginning of the specific function at **Controller**.

```
   /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function view(): View
    {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // 0 = Unlimited
        $student = new Student();
        $students = $student->searchStudents()->paginate(10);
        $custom = new Student();
        $customs = $custom->all();
        return view('admin.students.custom', compact('students','customs'));
    }
```